# How to undecimate and make shift invariant a Dual-tree Complex Discrete Wavelet Transform in R

Tags: wavelet

I have the following vector and wavelet transform (from R waveslim package)

```
x<-c(0.1,0.4,0.1,-0.05,0.025,0.12,0.42,0.14,-0.15,0.25,0.35,0.23,0.11,-0.35,0.025,0.1,0.4,0.1,-0.05,0.025,-0.12,0.2,0.09,-0.05,0.05,0.15,0.13,0.21,-0.15,0.023,0.1,0.4,0.1,-0.05,0.025,0.12,0.42,0.14,-0.15,0.25,0.35,0.23,0.11,-0.35,0.025)
J = 8
Faf = FSfarras()$af
    Fsf = FSfarras()$sf
af = dualfilt1()$af
    sf = dualfilt1()$sf
w = dualtree(x, J, Faf, af)
w
#For the synthesis of w, the output is
idualtree(w, J, Fsf, sf)
```

Would you happen to know if there is a function or mix of functions in any R package that may undecimate and make shift invariant the above transform, I have reviewed the packages in R and could not find any of this two functions. Otherwise it will be very helpful if you could drive me over the steps to carry over the above mentioned processes.

Comment: I doubt most people here are familiar with R specifically. Comments in your code and some links to the package documentation would be very helpful.